# I need that this function return the "difference" between this arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
prices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and this functions:

```
function less(value, prices) {
    return prices.filter(p => p <= value);
 }
  
 function more(value, prices){
    return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
 }


**function between(less, more, prices){
    let soma = less(value, prices).concat(more(value, prices))
    
    return prices.filter(x => !soma.includes(x))

}**
```

How can I use the function between for returning the difference between less and more?
For example:

```
between(5, 10, [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) -----> the function return is an array: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I only can change the **between function**.
I tried use the loop for, but doesn't work. :/

Comment: There are several problems with this code. For one you cannot just change the literal language you are using. It's not going to magically know that `precos` means `prices`, it's going to error out on all the undefined variables and methods you are using here.

Comment: Sorry about that.. i forgot that i don't changed this variables when i wrote here. The variable in the origin code is with the right name.I tried to change it to make more easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Array.concat` you can just use the output of the `more` function as an argument of the `less` function, and here is the correction:

```
function less(value, prices) {
    return prices.filter(p => p <= value);
}
  
function more(value, prices){
    return prices.filter(p => p >= value);
}

function between(l, m, prices){
    return less(m, more(l,prices));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's right. 
Now i think that i can understand... it's the function inside the function, inside the function. lol